# Pip, NumPy, and Pytorch Gone After Upgrading From Python3.6 to 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.8

I recently decided to upgrade to python3.8 from python3.6. I attempted to do this via Conda, but I'm not sure I'm sure I did things correctly. Now when I type python into my terminal, I get python2.7. If I type python3, I get python3.8.5, but I can't use any of the modules I previously downloaded (ie NumPy). Any ideas on how I can fix this / check what's going on?

Comment: Reinstall them?

Comment: When you update that much, you'll need to reinstall third-party modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to reinstall all of them

here is how:

open terminal and run

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

after pip is installed run

```
pip install numpy torch torchvision
```